Best way to connect the ReactJS with Spring MVC using maven build
i wanted to migrate the All JSP pages to Reactjs
i wanted to connect my reactjs with spring mvc
what are all the ways to connect reactjs with spring framework
what is the best way to connect?
i thought of trying with making proxy setting in package.json anf route the request
other way is bundle the js file inside my spring application war
i need some clarity and best and efficient way of doing
